# Ubuntu 20.04.1 - Laptop - suspension stops music

Tags: power-management, settings, lid

I have a Samsung laptop that I maintain plugged and charging all night, and at the same time, I use VLC to listen some relaxing music to sleep. If I close the lid, the music stops after a minute. If I leave the lid open, it stops after 2 hours. I can't make it keep on during the whole night.

I've been modifying some things in settings>Power, and the configuration seems to be ok for what I want: Blackscreen: 1 min (which doesn't stop the music if I leave the lid open); Automatic Suspension: Only when on battery power.

I also checked some solutions [like this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/05/lid-close-behavior-ubuntu-20-04/) about modifying the logind.conf, but most solutions are for 20.04, not 20.04.1, and it seems it doesn't work. I edited this archive saying that closing the lip should only lock my screen. Still I have the same behaviour.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install gnome-tweak-tool using `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`
2. Open tweak tool by typing tweak in activities menu
3. In the first option General, there is option to switch off the behavior.
   Check the image ..> [Gnome-tweak-tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVLRT.png)

Further, you can install "caffeine" gnome extension to keep off the suspension at your will.